# collecting queries from a google search form

Tags: html, forms, search

I have the following form:

```
<form id="search_form" method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search" onsubmit="runsearch(this);return false;" target='search'>
```

How can I collect the search queries entered into the form to a DB?

Answer (score 0):

Without having any knowledge of your server setup, this is as specific as I can get. Appropriately, google is what is going to help you figure out how to do the following:

1. Make a database. Ask your hosting provider what kind of DBs are offered and what is on your server and make a username/password for a user of that database. the most common is MySQL accessed through control panel or phpMyAdmin
2. Make your table called "Searches" either through the web GUI (likely) or with a SQL script
3. Define your data structure for that table usually a creation date, id, and content
4. Have the javascript in runsearch() also submit a query string or json data to the backend
5. have the backend connect to your database and insert a row containing the search data

Comment: Thanks for the answer FlavorScape, I've went through steps 1-3. Could you please provide more info on steps 4 and 5?